# Convert hex string to decimal char by char

Tags: shell, unix

I have an HEX string, and I what to convert each character in it to DEC, and to output them with space separated and in brackets. see example:

```
input: "A1B2C3D4"
output: "[10 1 11 2 12 3 13 4 ]"
```

Comment: What did you try and what is not working ?

Comment: Using python!  Prob. faster and more readable.

Comment: Why does everyone silently downvote a newbie?  Your are making this a really unfriendly place.  If you are going to downvote, then leave a COMMENT!!!

Comment: I do upvote every question that is downvoted for no reason

Comment: This question wasn't downvoted "for no reason". It shows zero research effort. The OP didn't show that he tried anything; he just wants code.

Comment: @GeorgeNetu  Bravo!  (How else are new people supposed to learn?)

Comment: The OP doesn't know anything.  His reputation is 1.

Comment: Having 1 rep is no excuse for writing bad questions. Everyone gets the tutorial and tour when they sign up. The rules are always available.

Comment: Reason why he/she has to invest some time and effort in researching how this site works and also how to "code" his/her problem. I suggest using a piece of paper and pencil for this exercise.

Comment: It is true that question doesn't show any effort from OP but I still believe we need to guide newbies better than just silently downvoting them.

Comment: I would add a comment regarding OP's question: you should fix the problem in your `output`. because `HEX 'D' = DEC '13'` not `14`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this awk one-liner does the job:

```
awk -v FS='' --non-decimal-data '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%d%s","0x"$i,(i==NF?RS:" ")}'
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "A1B2C3D4"|awk -v FS='' --non-decimal-data '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%d%s","0x"$i,(i==NF?RS:" ")}'
10 1 11 2 12 3 13 4
```

here two things need to pay attention :

- `--non-decimal-data` option for gawk to recognize hex input
- add a leading `0x` to each hex digit.

#### EDIT

an alternative with  build-in `printf`:

```
awk -v FS=''  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){"printf \"%d\" \"0x"$i"\""|getline v;printf "%d%s",v,(i==NF?RS:" ")}}'
```

test:

```
kent$   echo "A1B2C3D4"|awk -v FS=''  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){"printf \"%d\" \"0x"$i"\""|getline v;printf "%d%s",v,(i==NF?RS:" ")}}'
10 1 11 2 12 3 13 4
```

Comment: @user3748817 please leave meaningful comment.  I guess you don't have gnu-awk.

Comment: I think I do have it, this for example is working for me: > echo "1234" | awk NF=NF FS=
1 2 3 4

Comment: your awk is not `gnu` awk. check your awk version. if this works there? btw: `echo "ibase=16; D"|bc`

Comment: the printf alternative worked for me!!!!: awk -v FS=''  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){"printf \"%d\" \"0x"$i"\""|getline v;printf "%d%s",v,(i==NF?RS:" ")}}'. now I only need to add brackets, can you please help me with this one?